# How can I set the 'static' folder when it is not on the index folder, with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to build a site. I have the *index* folder and the *connected* folder. Each folder also has a *static* folder. In the *connected/static* folder, I have the *connected.css* file, which I am trying to access, through my blueprint. However, the final page tries to access the *connected.css* from the *index/static* folder.

Where am I mistaking?

Useful code:

**__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from .index import index_routes
from .connected import connected_routes


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")
    app.register_blueprint(index_routes.index_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(connected_routes.connected_bp, url_prefix='/connected')
    return app
```

**connected_routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template

connected_bp = Blueprint('connected_bp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static', url_prefix='/connected')  

@connected_bp.route('/')
def connected():
    return render_template('connected.html', title="Connected to Hattrick")
```

**index_routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template

index_bp = Blueprint('index_bp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@index_bp.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', title="The Best Match Predictor")
```

**connected.html**

```
<link href="{{url_for('static',filename='connected.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the above line I have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give this a try:

```
<link href="{{url_for('connected.static',filename='connected.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

For some elaboration: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#static-files

Comment: Actually, it's `connected_bp.static` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, and yes my bad, the url_prefix is to make the endpoint accesible. The blueprint name is used in url_for